# Unstable memory/mysql usage on 2.3.3, can't find the issue

Tags: magento2.3.3, memory

This is regarding a Magento 2.3.3 running on Digital Ocean's server 4GB memory droplet, which should be plenty as it is the only thing hosted on there. However, I have observed since upgrade to 2.3.3 from 2.3.0, there is some instability in memory usage which then leads to the site crashing with Varnish cache or http500 error during checkout. The memory limit for Magento is set to 3GB all around.

Below are the memory usage in the last 7 days:
[image: 7 days server memory graph]

Normally the memory usage should be less than 1GB (not much traffic), however, I have noticed there is a pattern where the memory would slowly build up to about 2GB, then something crashed and it falls back to the normal range and then the cycle repeats.

I have run the htop command, which I find MySQL is using the majority of the memory and the connection time is more than an hour, not sure if this is normal. However, by restarting the MySQL service, the memory would fall back to the normal range, which is about 
[image: htop screenshot]

Not sure exactly how to troubleshot this, so any help is appreciated!

Comment: there is not much info you have. please check logs at the time it crashes. something like memory leak, if only issue in checkout then you can test it,

Comment: Additional information request. 
# cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) complete MySQLTuner report 
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a Linux/Unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: check your magento cron log and your server cron , there might be some heavy operation running or a deadlock

Comment: @jerry         Could you post A) SELECT * FROM information_schema.global_variables WHERE variable_name LIKE '%thread%' OR 
variable_name LIKE 'max%conn%' ORDER BY variable_name 
; 
 AND B) SELECT * FROM information_schema.global_status WHERE variable_name LIKE '%thread%' OR variable_name = 'uptime' ORDER BY variable_name;
 for analysis of these few pieces of information.